# URL query format, CGI script request

Tags: url, cgi

What is the CGI script executed when we construct URL as follows:

> somesite.xx/content/?query=somestaff

after '?' sing we pass arguments, but script name looks like empty string between '/' and '?' signs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is defined by server configuration, which should have a "default document" for the directory in question.

Comment: For most configurations, index.xxx,  home.xxx, default.xxx, isn't it? But I guess, at least for apache, it can always be interpreted via mod_rewrite and point to a completely different path.

Comment: @AJweb I can't say for various servers to make a conclusion of "most", but for Apache this can be changed via .htaccess and via site config, and via mod_rewrite, so there are plenty of ways.